# Google sign-in method doesn't work when I publish it on the Play Store

Tags: flutter, firebase, mobile, google-signin, mobile-development

I recently added the Google Sign-In method to my Flutter project, and I've thoroughly checked all SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys. Everything seems to be working fine. However, when I publish my app on the Play Store, it doesn't work. I also use Google Crashlytics to catch errors, but no errors are appearing in my console.

*An important note:* Before I started this project, there was another Flutter project on the Play Store, and I updated this project by using the same package names.

UPDATE:(14.09.2023),

Some of the steps I've taken to resolve this issue include:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syONG.jpg)

```
Adding the application signing and upload keys from Google Play Console to the SHA-1 keys in Firebase project settings.
Requesting a new SHA-1 signing and upload key from Google Play Console.
Finally, I added the debug and release mode keys to Firebase, but the problem still persists.
```

here are the codes:
`google sign-in code`
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
await _googleSignIn.signIn();

```
  if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    return await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
} catch (error, stackTrace) {
  print("Google Sign In Error: $error");
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace);
}
```

}

-i have checked all keys and Firebase configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally identified the issue: all I had to do was find the old project that used the Google Play App Signing key and remove its SHA key from the Google Cloud Console.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this step and made sure Google has approved it if necessary?

`Make sure you've filled out all required fields in the console for OAuth consent screen. Otherwise, you may encounter APIException errors.`

I also noticed you write `if (googleSignInAccount != null) {...}` but there is nothing tracking if the googleSignInAccount is null. I would change it to record an error if it is null via

```
  if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    return await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  } else {
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(Exception("Oh no G Account is Null"), StackTrace.current);
}
} catch (error, stackTrace) {
  print("Google Sign In Error: $error");
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace);
}
```

Comment: you are right i need to test again

Comment: I am also getting this warning when signing the app:

Comment: Warning:
The signer's certificate is self-signed.
The SHA1 algorithm specified for the -digestalg option is considered a security risk and is disabled.
The SHA1withRSA algorithm specified for the -sigalg option is considered a security risk and is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Play Store signs the app again. I believe this happens when you opt in to use the "upload key".

You can find the SHA1 fingerprint that Play Store uses under Release->Setup->App signing. If you add that SHA1 to Firebase your release app's Google Sign In should start to work without an app update.

Comment: I initially tried this step. In my application, there was another app with the same package name on Google Play Store before, so I created a new project and set the package name to match that app. I requested to reset the SHA-1 signing keys for the Firebase project I created for this app in the Google Play Console and added the new keys to Firebase, but the problem still persists.

Comment: What you wrote does not make sense beginning with "set the package name to match that app".

Comment: I had an application on the Google Play Store. I created a new Flutter project with the same package name and signed the application with the old keystore file, then uploaded it to the Google Play Store.

Comment: Yeah whatever you do, your user ends up with an apk that has some package id, that is signed with some SHA1 and that uses a Firebase project. That Firebase project needs to be given that SHA1 key under the app record with that package id. You can download the apk off of play store and look in that apk to find the SHA1 that was actually used. Google "download apk off of play store" and "determine sha1 in apk".

Comment: If you're able to do that you'll realize that my answer here was all you needed.

Comment: I downloaded the APK file and extracted the SHA key from it, but when I added it to Firebase, I got the error.(I added it to the post images)

Comment: I think I've added all the SHA keys related to the application to Firebase and Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Normally you don't add anything to Google Cloud Console... As I explained you can check the apk that the user downloads to see the SHA1 that you are missing.

Comment: I think my problem is related to this support page but I can't solve it  https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008?hl=en#zippy=%2Ci-deleted-the-app-but-i-still-receive-an-oauth-client-already-exists-message%2Ci-deleted-the-project-but-i-still-receive-an-oauth-client-already-exists-message%2Ci-dont-know-which-project-contains-the-conflicting-oauth-client-id

Comment: I found the solution to the problem and added it as a response. Thanks for your support.